# Linux set source IP address at boot

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I’m running Debian box with one network interface that has two IP addresses:

```
192.168.1.2/24 (192.168.1.1 is gateway)
192.168.100.1/32 (using anycast).
```

I want the `192.168.100.1` to be a source for all requests, but 192.168.1.2 is used instead.

Using

```
ip route change default via 192.168.1.1 src 192.168.100.1
```

I can change it, but I don’t know, how to set it permanently in `/etc/network/interfaces`, only idea I have is use `up` rule. Is there some cleaner way (I don't like up rules, they are really ugly)?